# Can't install aws.s3 package in R Studio Server on Ubuntu 18.04 - permission denied?

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, privileges, rstudio-server

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, EC2 machine.

Please guide me how to enable R Studio Server to install aws.s3 package.

Here is what I am doing:

```
install.packages(c('aws.s3', 'aws.signature'), repos = c('cloudyr' = 'http://cloudyr.github.io/drat'), lib = "/vg1/lv1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/")
```

Where `vg1/lv1/` is my non root mounted 250GB disk.

Here is the error:

```
Installing package into ‘/vg1/lv1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) also installing the dependency ‘aws.signature’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/aws.signature_0.5.0.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 24939 bytes (24 KB)
================================================== downloaded 24 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/aws.s3_0.3.12.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 47424 bytes (46 KB)
================================================== downloaded 46 KB

* installing *source* package ‘aws.signature’ ...
** package ‘aws.signature’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location Warning in file(con, "rb") :   cannot open file '/home/ssolun/.aws/credentials': Permission denied Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘aws.signature’:  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'aws.signature', details:   call: file(con, "rb")  error: cannot open the connection Error: loading failed Execution halted ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/vg1/lv1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/aws.signature’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘aws.signature’ had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘aws.signature’ is not available for package ‘aws.s3’
* removing ‘/vg1/lv1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/aws.s3’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘aws.s3’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in   ‘/tmp/RtmpAkWgxm/downloaded_packages’
```

Please guide me how to enable the access to R Studio Server to actually install this package?

Answer (score 1):

Found out!
This occurred because of wrong user owning the file.

Here is what I did and solved the issue, hope it will help others:

```
sudo chown your_user_name .aws/credentials
```